# Function in Python game not breaking and won't continue to next function

Tags: python, function, numbers

For a class we have to make a game where a person will enter an upper integer and a lower integer for a range. Then a random number is picked from in between those two numbers. The player would then guess a number and the game would end when you guessed the right number. In the function for my range I have a loop that will only end when you enter a correct range. It will then clear the console and continue to the guessing part of the game. The problem is once you enter a correct range it will clear the screen, then execute the wrong part of the loop and make it impossible to continue. What I have programmed so far is below, I started Python about 2 months ago.

```
**import time, os, random

#The beginning where you enter a range
def game_loop():
 got_an_int = False
 while got_an_int == False:
  user_input1 = input("Enter the upper bound integer of the range:  ")
  user_input2 = input('Enter the lower bound integer of the range:  ')
   try: 
     user_input1 = int(user_input1)
     user_input2 = int(user_input2)
     print("Good job, that is a correct range.")
     got_an_int = True
     clear()
     break
   except:
    print("That is not a correct range. Try again.")

#To continue after entering a correct range
def clear():
  time.sleep(3)
  os.system('clear')
  time.sleep(1)
  game_begin()

#Random Number Generator
def random_num(a,b):
  random.randint(user_input1,user_input2)

#Where you begin the game
def game_begin():
  guess_right = False
  random_num = random_num(user_input1,user_input2)
  while  random_num != guess_right:
   guess = input('Guess an integer in your range: ')
   total_guess = [] + 1
   try:
     guess = int(guess)
     if random_num > guess:
       print("Too Low.")
       guess_right = False
     if random_num < guess:
        print('Too High.')
        guess_right = False
        guess = int(guess)
     if random_num == guess:
        print("You got it! Good job.")
        guess_right = True
        the_end()
   except:
      print("That is not an int. Try again")**
```

Comment: in `while  random_num != guess_right:` you compare number with `True/False` which makes no sense. You should rather check `while  guess_right is False:` or shorter `while not guess_right:` Eventually `while  random_num != guess:` and then you don't need `guess_right`

Comment: what do you have in `the_end()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple problems, but the most glaring one is a combination of a few things:

```
random_num = random_num(user_input1, user_input2)
```

First, this line re-assigns the `random_num` symbol to be the result of calling `random_num`. After this line happens, any future calls to `random_num` won't work, because the function is "gone". Second, both `user_input1` and `user_input2` are not in scope in the `game_begin` function (they belong to the `game_loop` function).

Both of these problems are hidden because you're using "naked" excepts:

```
try:
    ...
except:
    print(...)
```

You should only catch the Exceptions you're expecting and handle them appropriately, or make it so those exceptions won't happen.

In the end, I was able to get it to *mostly* work with the following. Additional problems I encountered are mentioned in the comments.

```
import time, os, random

def game_loop():
    got_an_int = False
    while got_an_int == False:
        user_input1 = input("Enter the upper bound integer of the range:  ")
        user_input2 = input('Enter the lower bound integer of the range:  ')
        try: 
            user_input1 = int(user_input1)
            user_input2 = int(user_input2)
            print("Good job, that is a correct range.")
            got_an_int = True
            clear()

            # Move game_begin call here and use parameters, so that randint call works
            game_begin(user_input1, user_input2)
            break
        except:
            print("That is not a correct range. Try again.")

def clear():
    time.sleep(3)
    os.system('clear')
    time.sleep(1)

# Remove this - not needed
# def random_num(a,b):
#     random.randint(user_input1,user_input2)

def game_begin(in1, in2):
    guess_right = False

    # No longer overwriting variable/func symbol
    # Also, reverse order since range is taken Highest first then Lowest
    random_num = random.randint(in2, in1)

    # Initialize total_guess to 0
    total_guess = 0
    while random_num != guess_right:
        guess = input('Guess an integer in your range: ')

        # Can't add list and ints. I assume you wanted to keep a running total?
        # Lists aren't how you would do that.
        total_guess += 1
        try:
            guess = int(guess)
            if random_num > guess:
                print("Too Low.")
                guess_right = False
            if random_num < guess:
                print('Too High.')
                guess_right = False
                guess = int(guess)
            if random_num == guess:
                print("You got it! Good job.")
                guess_right = True

                # This function doesn't exist, so the loop won't ever actually end
                # NameError exception is raised
                the_end()
        except:
            print("That is not an int. Try again")
```

Comment: What are your inputs? I just tested it and it runs, assuming you give upper bound (large number) and then lower bound (smaller number than previous). If you give inputs the other way around (small number, then larger number), then yes you'll see that happen because `random.randint(...)` will throw a ValueError, which is getting hidden by the naked `try...except`. If you _remove_ the `try/excepts` (or make them more specific), the resulting tracebacks will tell you what's going wrong, and where.